# Punctuation with declarative sentence in narration

Tags: punctuation

I have two versions of this sentence:

> *Stop moping and get going! she told herself.*

Or should it be

> *Stop moping and get going, she told herself!*

So where do the comma and exclamation point go? This comes up with comma and question marks as well.

Comment: I would definitely put the exclamation mark after _going_, as the last part isn't an exclamation.

Comment: Same with *Should I really go? she asked herself.* These are actually non-quoted, non-spoken-aloud  internal dialog statements.